# Git hooks file naming

Tags: git

I wanted to install some custom hooks to forbid committing/pushing to master branch locally, but was puzzled by the Git documentation on the custom hooks usage and file naming.
Here is excerpt from https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks:

> All the examples are written as shell scripts, with some Perl thrown
> in, but any properly named executable scripts will work fine – you can
> write them in Ruby or Python or what have you. If you want to use the
> bundled hook scripts, you’ll have to rename them; their file names all
> end with .sample.
>
> To enable a hook script, put a file in the hooks subdirectory of your
> Git directory that is named appropriately and is executable. From that
> point forward, it should be called. We’ll cover most of the major hook
> filenames here.

So I have two questions:

1. What is exactly this "appropriate" naming that is referred to in the docs? AFAICS it is not defined on that page.
2. If e.g. a custom pre-commit script is used (not the bundled pre-commit.sample), will it override the bundled one assuming the bundled one is also kept intact in the hooks directory, or will the both run one after each other and if yes, in what order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook files/scripts are named like given in the documentation.

`git help hooks` shows the names explicitly:

```
HOOKS

   ...

   pre-commit
       This hook is invoked by git commit, and can ...
```

If you prefer to read about them online, they are also in the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks):

> The `pre-commit` hook is run first, before...

The files are then named literally like this, i.e., `.git/hooks/pre-commit`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with hooks is that they can't be committed to your repo.

There are a few solutions to help with that, and I also wrote mine, aiming simplicity and extensibility, and to work with any programming language.

https://pypi.org/project/hooks4git

You can find others at:

https://githooks.com/